# How can I make the svg stretch to the width of the parent while keeping the size of the central circle and its height?

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, header

[image: header-img-png]

It is 320px wide, but when the container grows I want only the width of the svg to grow, keeping the size of the center circles

[image: mobile]

```html
<svg width="320" height="64" viewBox="0 0 320 64" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M160 39C177.673 39 192 24.6731 192 7C192 4.59551 191.735 2.25296 191.232 0L320 0V64H0V0L128.768 0C128.265 2.25296 128 4.59551 128 7C128 24.6731 142.327 39 160 39Z" fill="#0E0B16"/>
</svg>
```

#### There is other way to do it with html and css only?

Comment: remove the width and height attributes

Comment: Could you add a picture of what your goal is?

Comment: @Rojo I just uploaded an image (mobile)

Comment: Could you post a bit more code, like the container and the search picture?

Answer (score 0):

A CSS only solution:

```css
.box {
  height:80px;
  background:black; /*              radius at position          */
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle 30px at 50% 5px,transparent 97%,#fff);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Another syntax more supported:

```css
.box {
  height:80px;
  background:black; 
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle 30px,transparent 97%,#fff)
    0 100%/
    100% 190%; /* adjust the 190% to control the position */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```